# how to share a transaction in two dbContext with EF6?

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

I am using EF6 and I know that has two methods to use a transaction, BeginTransaction and UseTransaction.

I use to use only one dbContext, but in my case, I need to use an auxiliar dbContext and I need that this second dbContext use the same transaction that the main one. I try to use this code:

```
using(Entities miDbContext = new Entities())
{
    using (DbContextTransaction miTransaccion = miDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        Entities miDbContext2 = new Entities();
        miDbContext2.DataBase.UseTransaction(miTransaccion);
    }
}
```

But I get an error in the UseTransaction because miTrasaccion is not of the correct type.

I would like to know how I can shared the same transaction between two dbContexts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the connection of miDbContext to miDbContext2 first.

Try the below code. It should work.

```
Entities miDbContext2 = new Entities(miDbContext.Database.Connection, false);
miDbContext2.DataBase.UseTransaction(miTransaccion.UnderlyingTransaction);
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to SajidQ's answer with the better syntax

```
  miDbContext2.Database.UseTransaction(dbContextTransaction.UnderlyingTransaction);
```