# Multiple EF databases Can I avoid MSDTC?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, transactionscope, msdtc

I have two SQL Server databases (with different tables) and an Entity Framework DbContext which represents each one of those. Tables on each of these contexts will get CRUDed as part of a business process. At the end of the process I want to use a transaction to make sure that everything gets saved, or nothing. So far, the only way I can get this to work is by using code similar to the below:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{   
    DataMgr.EFAccount.SaveChanges();
    DataMgr.EFCompany.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Unfortunately, this code uses MSDTC which causes an extra  performance hit I really want to avoid. I have heard that you can get rid of MSDTC if you use the same connection for all the database updates. However, each of these DbContexts have their own connection to the database, an I cannot find a way to change the connection on a DbContext after it has already been created.

Does anyone know of a way I might be able to avoid MSDTC in this situation? We are using EF 6.0, .NET framework 4.5.2 and SQL Server 2012. We are currently using database first - but that may change.

Comment: You see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382070/how-to-share-a-transaction-in-two-dbcontext-with-ef6

Comment: In my case the DbContexts were created previous to this code - so the method they used would probably not work. I will play with passing in an already existing connection (to another database) to my Dbcontext at creation time - but I am not optimistic.

Comment: As I suspected, passing in a connection object (from another database context) at creation time, does not work for this scenario. You can create the DbContext fine, but if you try and do anything with it - it will give you an error. The problem is that the database first connection string passes in a lot of database specific information (csdl, ssdl, etc) that the DbConext is depending on, and when you take that away problems happen. This method might work with a code first EF set up, but it does not work for a database first setup.

Comment: I switched my application to "code first" and passing the connection to the new context does not work for me. The second context cannot find the tables it needs because the connection is pointing to the first database.